# Get file size info in Notebook with $magic

Tags: python, ipython

Is it possible to get file size info with a magic command in notebook?

I've searched the internet but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is !ls -lh which returns info about file size

Comment: `!stat -f '%z' <file>` will get the size only, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not relative to IPython but you may use the os library in Python, it’s very simple as well. More specifically, you can get the size of a file using

```py
import os
size_bytes = os.stat(<put_file_name_here>).st_size
```

Note: the result will be in bytes so you can divide by 1 000 000 if you want the result to be in MB.